# Loop through array, and convert child JSON to observablearray?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, knockout.js

This is probably a pretty known issue, and probably already solved in Stack Overflow, but I've searched without any luck.

I have this array which consists of a JSON-string. I'm trying to loop through the array, and convert the JSON to an observablearray so I can access the properties "value", "name", "price" so I can use it with Knockout.

**Array with JSON :**

```
0
:
"{"value":"382","name":"Entrecoté med poteter og sånt..","price":295.0}"
1
:
"{"value":"385","name":"Svinekoteletter","price":295.0}"
2
:
"{"value":"386","name":"Pizza Margherita","price":255.0}"
```

**Initial loop :**

```
completeArray.forEach(function(c) {
            // convert the json string to an observableArray ??
        });
```

### Edited

If someone else comes to find a solution to how to do this, I include the complete example below:

```
self.addFoodItemsToSubMenu = function (item) {
        var existingFIS = JSON.parse(ko.toJSON(item.foodItemList()));
        var newFIS = JSON.parse(ko.toJSON(self.selectedFoodItems()));
        var completeFIS = existingFIS.concat(newFIS);

        var resultArray = ko.observableArray(completeFIS.map(function (item) {
            var parsedResult = JSON.parse(item);
            var resultObject = {
                value: parsedResult.value,
                name: parsedResult.name,
                price: ko.observable(parsedResult.price)
            }
            return resultObject;
        }));

        item.foodItemList(resultArray());
        self.selectedFoodItems([]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood you right:

```
var resultArray = ko.observableArray(completeArray.map(function(item) {
    return JSON.parse(item);
}));
```

Comment: I see that this is the wanted result indeed!.. Will have to make the "price" property as observable though.. since it's going to be edited.. Know how i can do that ?

Comment: Okay.. your approach solved the riddle.. I have updated the question with the complete function, in case someone comes around to look for the same solution...

Answer (score 0):

I would use map since it will loop through each item in the array, transform it, and spit it back out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I will check this as once :) Thanks for swift commenting!